# Access gameObject array value from other script

Tags: unity

I'm trying to access gameobject array values from one script to another. I have attached certain gameobject capsules with the array in the editor as shown in the figure below and I'm trying to access the values of array to another script. But I get null values when i try to pass the values. I don't want to use gameobject tag since i have to set gameobject active and deactive during runtime.

**PinsScript.cs**

```
public class PinsScript : MonoBehaviour {

        // Use this for initialization
        public GameObject[] pins;
        void Start () {

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {

        }
}
```

**MovingBall.cs**

```
PinsScript p = GetComponent<PinsScript>();

        foreach (GameObject pin in p.pins)
        {

             pin.SetActive(false);



        }
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good to me. Are both scripts on the same gameObject?. What's the exact error?

Comment: No they are attached to different gameobject

Comment: There isn't any error, its just that the object carries null value.

Comment: Obviously. If they're not attached to the same gameObject, then the statement `PinsScript p = GetComponent<PinsScript>();` is wrong. Because, it's trying to find the _PinsScript_ component in the same gameObject, which is not there, as you said.

Comment: Well the condition is different here, I have to run the Movingball script at runtime and not at the start of the game. Is there other way that i can proceed with?

Answer (score 1):

Attach a PinScript to each pin.  Keep a reference to each of your pins in an array when you Awake.  Your PinScript can be empty.  Then you have a reference to turn them on or off as you please.  Your scripts would look like this:

PinScript.cs

```
public class PinsScript : MonoBehaviour { }
```

MovingBall.cs

```
public class MovingBall : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PinsScript[] pinScripts;

    private void Awake()
    {
        pinScripts = FindObjectsOfType<PinsScript>();
    }

    public void SetPinActivity(bool active)
    {
        foreach (var pin in pinScripts)
        {
            pin.gameObject.SetActive(active);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can deactivate them by calling:

```
myMovingBall.SetPinActivity(false);
```

This, however, is not a great architecture.  But it is a simple solution.

I assume you do not know how many pins you have.  If you know your pins ahead of time, let me know, and I will suggest a more optimized solution.  But this will work either way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is with referencing **which PinsScript are you trying to access.**

Whenever you are instanciating a new MovingBall, you **must** reference the PinsScript somewhere. I usually do this by adding a small portion of code on the MonoBehavior which create the MovingBall :

```
public PinsScript pinsScript;
```

Then, you just have to drag the GameObject holding the PinsScript into that variable. Another way to do it is by accessing the GameObject by name :

```
PinsScript p = GameObject.Find("TheNameOfTheGameObjectHoldingThePinsScript").GetComponent<PinsScript>();
```

Comment: I think this pretty much answers the question. Why's the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there is a slight change that worked for me. GameObject.FindWithTag instead of GameObject.Find. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Both _GameObject.FindWithTag_ and _GameObject.Find_ will work. The difference is that the former takes the _Name_ of the Object as argument while the latter takes a _tag_.

Comment: Again, I didnt downvote; but GameObject.Find is often persuaded against, as it is inefficient and laggy. Users may find that this is not an appropriate solution, at a certain number of gameobjects.

Comment: Giving this a +1 because `GameObject.Find` will work. The caveat is that it shoudn't be used *in `Update()`*